# Convolutional AE always overfitting time series - what’s wrong?

Tags: time-series, pytorch, conv-neural-network, autoencoder, anomaly-detection

I've build a CAE for anomaly detection in time series, but it is always overfitting. I've tried data augmentation, short/long inputvector, dropout rates... I don't know what I'm doing wrong, may be you can give me a hint?

This is my architecture

```py
class CAE(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CAE, self).__init__()

        self.encoder = Encoder()
        self.decoder = Decoder()

        self.encoder.to(get_device())
        self.decoder.to(get_device())

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.encoder(x)
        x = self.decoder(x)
        return x

class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()

        self.conv_enc = nn.Sequential(
            nn.AlphaDropout(p=0.5),
            nn.Conv1d(
                in_channels=1,
                out_channels=16,
                kernel_size=5,
                stride=2,
                padding=0
            ),
            nn.SELU(),
            nn.AlphaDropout(p=0.5),
            nn.Conv1d(
                in_channels=16,
                out_channels=8,
                kernel_size=5,
                stride=2,
                padding=0
            ),
            nn.SELU()
        )

        self.conv_enc.apply(self.init_weights)
            
    def init_weights(self, m):
        if type(m) == nn.Conv1d or type(m) == nn.ConvTranspose1d:
            torch.nn.init.xavier_normal_(m.weight)
            m.bias.data.fill_(0.01)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv_enc(x)
        return x

class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()

        self.conv_dec = nn.Sequential(
             nn.ConvTranspose1d(
                in_channels=8,
                out_channels=16,
                kernel_size=5,
                stride=2,
                padding=0
            ),
            nn.SELU(),
            #nn.AlphaDropout(p=0.5),
            nn.ConvTranspose1d(
                in_channels=16,
                out_channels=1,
                kernel_size=6,
                stride=2,
                padding=0
            )
        )

        self.conv_dec.apply(self.init_weights)
            
    def init_weights(self, m):
        if type(m) == nn.Conv1d or type(m) == nn.ConvTranspose1d:
            torch.nn.init.xavier_normal_(m.weight)
            m.bias.data.fill_(0.01)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv_dec(x)
        return x
```

I'm using following setup

- optimizer - AdamW with lr=0.0001
- scheduler - OneCyleLR
- Normalized Data with MinMaxScaler()
- loss - L1Loss
- batchsize - 250
- trainingsize - 12000 sample
- inputsize - 800

[Loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uFxr.png)

[Acc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FNCu.png)

Thank you guys

**Append**

Inputsize = 140

[Smaller Area of Time Series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6rfi.png)

[Accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UmIK.png)

[Loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkYrE.png)

Comment: How do you know that it is overfitting?

Comment: I assume, because I'm experiencing an increasing validation loss and decreasing validation acc but remain constant training loss.

Comment: Can you provide a plot of your val/train losses across epochs?

Comment: Yeah, I've updated my post.

Comment: Those plots look pretty good?  Up until epoch 75 the model is progressing nicely, with decreasing validation loss. You can use early stopping to stop the model at that point.

Comment: Yeah, I've implemented an early stopping procedure and it works, but 80% accuracy is too bad for my task. I need something arround 99% to identify anomalies in the time series with minimal deviation. I've already tried data augmentation up to 50K samples and retrained the models, it improved a bit but not too much. I have to feeling that some sections of the time series performs pretty bad in the training as well as the test phase. I'll add an example to my post.

Comment: To debug that one would need to see 10+ examples of "normal" along with 10 examples of "anomaly" class. Then it may be possible to understand whether this is detectable at 99% accuracy - and what kind of method might be suitable for that. Note that is more of a Data Science SE question than SO (not programming)

Comment: You could be right :) I've asked there too. I'm training only one class and hope to detect a deviation via bad reconstruction error. If the accuracy is too low the data can not or only bed reconstructed :/

Comment: Can you link your Data Science SE question?

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/90205/convolutional-ae-always-overfitting-time-series-what-s-wrong